# Get position of an UIView in an UIImageView

Tags: swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I have the following:

[image]

(1) Is a Giphy. I want to be able to move the giphy to the trash. I get the coordinates of the giphy with:

```
    print("position of finger in moving giphy")
    let position = gesture.location(in: imageViewImageTaken)
```

I struggle to get the position of my "trash" icon. This icon is a subview of my UIImageView, which is a photo.

I tried to get the position of the "trash" icon with:

```
let positionTrash = imageViewBin.convert(imageViewBin.bounds, to: imageViewImageTaken)
```

But when I move my finger to the trash icon and get the coordinates of (1) it does not match.

How can I correctly receive the position of (2)?

Comment: I don't think you need to convert anything if the trash is a subview of the image view. Just do `imageViewBin.frame` to get the frame of the trash in the coordinate space of the image view.

Comment: Hi Sweeper, these are the coordinates when my finger is EXACTLY on the trashIcon: frame
(185.0, 664.3333333333334, 44.0, 44.333333333333336)
position of thumb
(208.66665649414062, 686.3333282470703)

Comment: Yeah, that looks right to me. Those coordinates say your thumb is on the trash icon. Note that the trash icon has a width and a height, so your thumb is "on the trash icon" if it's coordinates are anywhere between (185, 664) and (229, 709). You can add the width and height to the position to get the upper bounds.

Comment: You can use [`CGRect.contains`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1456316-contains) to check whether a `CGRect` (the frame of the trash icon) contains a `CGPoint` (your finger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `frame` is the x, y, width, height of a view in its superview's coordinate system, you can use `frame` to get the x, y, width, height of the trash icon in the image view's coordinate system. There is no need to use `convert`:

```
let trashFrame = imageViewBin.frame
```

You seem to have another misunderstanding about how to check whether the finger is touching the trash. To do this, you need to check whether a `CGRect` (`trashFrame`) contains a `CGPoint` (`position`). This can be done using [`CGRect.contains`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1456316-contains):

```
if trashFrame.contains(position) {
    print("The finger is on the trash icon!")
}
```

Alternatively, get the location of the finger and check if it is in the `bounds` of the trash:

```
let position = gesture.location(in: imageViewBin)
if imageViewBin.bounds.contains(position) {

}
```